# How to remove HTML tags from the gridview Row

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have a textbox which uses the `CKeditor` functionality. The issue is that, when I add the text and links in the textboxes and submit it. I can the see the HTML tags also in the gridview like [this](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1014200221358)

What I want it that, whenever the data is added, it should hide/ make invisible the HTML tags.

Also see the HTML code for the textbox.

```
<ckeditor:ckeditorcontrol id="txtreportdescription" basepath="/ckeditor/" runat="server">
```

Comment: try below link http://www.andrewbarber.com/post/remove-html-attributes-and-tags-from-html-source.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the HTML render in the wanted column, Try :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="MyColumn" HtmlEncode="false" />
```