# gridview displaying data with html tags how to remove html tags while showing in grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

im inserting data into database with ckeditor like this `<strong>krishna<br /> <br /> <em>hyderabad</em></strong>`. but while displaying  data  in gridview its again coming with html tags, i want that should come in gridview with out html tags, itemdescription column having tags which i customized by fckeditor.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvChallan" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
        </asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["kernelCS"].ConnectionString)
;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select itemsdescription,quantity,totalboxes from tbl_DeliveryChallan",con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            gvChallan.DataSource = ds;
            gvChallan.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719898/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-the-gridview-row

Comment: ya thanks. but is it possible with autogeneratecolumn= true. i think not possible. @TimSchmelter

Comment: I think you can handle the `RowDataBound` event in codebehind and decode it manually: `e.Row.Cells[0].Text = Context.Server.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[0].Text)`

Comment: thanks...for sharing ur knowldge...@TimSchmelter